# Alternatives to GACUtil

Tags: c#, .net, dll, deployment, gacutil

I am working on a C# .NET Class Library project. This project is referenced by a lot other applications and requires frequent maintenance.

Every time there are changes, we may need to deploy the .dll manually to 10+ other application locations, which is very tedious work.

I am looking for a way that, I only need to deploy the .dll to only 1 location, and the other projects will automatically take the latest .dll when it restarts.

So far I only found GACUtil but am not considering it because it requires the assembly to be strongly named.

What I am trying to find is 
- Deploy to 1 location only
- Application should be able to stay running with the "older" version of DLL even after I deploy the "newer" version
- It is fine to restart the Application to "get latest" the DLL

Comment: What about Click-Once deployment in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to place a copy of your dll in the executing directory and load the assembly in the application with late binding. If references and early binding would be used, the dll-version would have to mach.

The alternative is to strongly name your managed dll and use GacUtil or an nsis installer-script.

Comment: If You decide to strongname the Assembly You could use .NET code to register in the GAC as described in [MS Knowledge Base, Article 317540](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/317540/en-us).